# mySQL unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, count, unique

I need to get unique values from a table. I have a single column with comma separated keywords. I need to derive a single list of all the keywords without duplicates. Getting the count of how often each keyword is present, too.

From what I have researched, it is an UNPIVOTING like function with an unknown number of columns?

**For example:**

keywords

---

- red, blue, yellow
- blue, orange, black, white
- brown, black, clear, pink
- blue, violet, orange

**Result**

color    | count

---

- red       1
- blue      3
- yellow    1
- orange    2
- black     2
- white     1
- brown     1
- clear     1
- pink      1
- violet    1

Thank you in advance!!

**
Thus far I have tried adding an explode_table type procedure, but realized I can't call that dynamically from a View. Then I have been experimenting with performing a reverse GROUP_CONCAT() on the column. I haven't been able to produce code that performs.

---

My version of echo_Me's answer:

```
    SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sKeywords, ',', n.n), ',', -1) value , count(*) as counts
FROM tblPatternMetadata t CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL  SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a, (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION  ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n ) n
    WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(sKeywords) - LENGTH(REPLACE(sKeywords, ',', ''))) group by value
```

Comment: post the query that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
    SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.keywords, ',', n.n), ',', -1) value , count(*) as counts
    FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN 
   (
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
   FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL  SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION  ALL SELECT 9) b

   ORDER BY n
 ) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.keywords) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.keywords, ',', '')))
 group by value
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e35c/1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A bit over my head, but I'm trying it out. I inserted my column name and try running it in Navicat. I get a 'View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause' error. I'll post my version of your statement in my question above.

Comment: whats wrong ? it works good in my demo , you must have done something wrong.

Comment: The code works great in the DEMO. And I can force phpMyAdmin and Navicat to run the statement. But if I try to save the statement into a view, it returns that error. argh.

Comment: I just read about mySQL not allowing subqueries. Which explains the error "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause". I wonder if it is possible to create a view from the subquery and then call that view in the original query?

Comment: you have other solution , is to reorganize your table and put the values separatly with the count. colors and counts . then you dont need subquery , you just need simple query. you have bad structure in your table. dont store values comma separated .

Comment: I agree about the bad structure. However I don't have power over the structure of the DB. I am tasked with getting the data for another application. I did have success with just calling the query from my PHP code. It works fine, and quick. So unless I find a reason that it won't work I will stick with that. THX again for your help @echo_Me